# How can I property output for application/x-ndjson

Tags: json, spring, ndjson

```java
@GetMapping(produces = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE
})
public Flux<Some> read() {
}
```

When I `curl` with `--header 'Accept: application/x-ndjson'`

The outer array is gone but all new lines in each elements is not gone.

```
{
  "some": "thing"
}
{
  "some": "other"
}
```

How can I make them as single-line as possible?

Comment: Prints two lines on my system.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using webflux and by your example you are.

```
    @CrossOrigin // to be able to test it
    @RestController
    public class Controller {

        @GetMapping(value = "/json/flux", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE)
        public Flux<Student> streamJsonObjects() {
            return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                    .take(10)
                    .map(i -> new Student("Name" + i, i.intValue()));
        }
    }
```

The DTO assuming you are using Project Lombok.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student {
    String name;
    int id;
}
```

Now how do you test it?

The best option I found was is Intellij http client
`GET http://localhost:8080/json/flux`

Other option is to press f12 in to open the web console and paste this in

```
const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/json/flux");
const reader = response.body.getReader();

while (true) {
    const {value, done} = await reader.read();
    if (done) break;
    const string = decoder.decode(value);
    console.log('Received', string);
}

console.log('Response fully received');
```